# Is there a bash equivalent for ruby %{} quoting?

Tags: bash, quote

What is the easiest way to quote bash command arguments that contain single quotes and double quotes without variable interpolation?

In Ruby you can quote strings using %{}, %[] etc. In that case single quotes and double quotes will be treated as characters.

My question was not really complete here is further explanation:

The reason I am asking that is because I often run ruby and perl code at the command line. Since those languages are using extensively single quotes and double quotes and global variables like $1 $_ etc. I get conflicts with bash.

example:

```
ls -lat | ruby -p -e '$_ =~ /(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)/; $_ = "'\''" + ($3 || "") + "'\''" + "\n"'
```

I was looking for something similar to the % quoting in ruby:

```
ls -lat | ruby -p -e %{$_ =~ /(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)/; $_ = "'" + ($3 || "") + "'" + "\n"}
```

Comment: Not confident to give an answer, but the Bash reference manual's section on quoting looks as if it is saying no: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't need variable interpolation, you can use `$'...'` quoting (although you still need to escape single quotes, so this might not fit your requirement):

```
x=$'String containing \' and "'
```

Comment: I didn't know about this type of quoting, it's better that what I am currently using. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Probably easiest with a heredoc:

```
read -r arg << \EOF
A string "with" 'quotes'
EOF
```

will set $arg to the uninterpolated content of the heredoc.  This does not allow newlines to be embedded in the variable.  If you want a multi-line value:

```
unset var; while read -r v; do var="$var${var+
}$v; done << \EOF
A multi-line "" string
with different 'quotes'
EOF
```

Ormaaj's comment using IFS, unfortunately, does not work to capture newlines.